# Convert ComboBox.TextBlock XAML to C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, attached-properties

I have the following fragment of XAML:

```
<ComboBox
    Name="comboBox1"
    IsEditable="True"
    Text="test"
    TextBlock.TextAlignment="Right" />
```

How do I convert that to C#? In particular, what does the TextBlock.TextAlignment become?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the [attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) of TextBlock that you have to use in C# code, commented in code below:

```
ComboBox cmb = new ComboBox();
cmb.Name = "comboBox1";
cmb.IsEditable = true;
cmb.Text = "Test";
TextBlock.SetTextAlignment(cmb, TextAlignment.Right); //here it is
```